# Using jQuery to replace one tag with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

### Goal:

Using jQuery, I'm trying to replace all the occurrences of:

```
<code> ... </code>
```

with:

```
<pre> ... </pre>
```

#### My solution:

I got as far as the following,

```
$('code').replaceWith( "<pre>" + $('code').html() + "</pre>" );
```

#### The problem with my solution:

but the issues is that it's replacing everything between the (second, third, fourth, etc)"code" tags with the content between the **first** "code" tags.

e.g.

```
<code> A </code>
<code> B </code>
<code> C </code>
```

becomes

```
<pre> A </pre>
<pre> A </pre>
<pre> A </pre>
```

I think I need to use "this" and some sort of function but I'm afraid I'm still learning and don't really understand how to piece a solution together.

Comment: Fixed the wrap-unwrap solution now jon - check it out ;)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can pass a function to [`.replaceWith` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$('code').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<pre />", {html: $(this).html()});
});
```

Inside the function, `this` refers to the currently processed `code` element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/k2swf/)

**Update:** There is [no big performance difference](http://jsperf.com/substituting-one-tag-for-another-with-jquery/4), but in case the `code` elements have other HTML children, appending the children instead of serializing them feels to be more correct:

```
$('code').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<pre />").append($(this).contents());
});
```

Comment: this seems to be the most elegant solution, tho i'll admit i don't understand what's going on inside the replaceWith function. would love to hear more. i.e. how is assigning the opening AND closing tags? does the space in <pre /> accomplish that?

Comment: @jon: It is a short hand for creating new elements. More information can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2. jQuery loops over all the elements and executes the function for each of them (same what `.each` is doing).

Comment: @jon: But check Jens' solution again, he fixed it.

Comment: +1 for a nice trick - this can be used for a lot more than just simple tag-for-tag substitution.

Comment: @FelixKling Wouldn't this overwrite the attributes of the code tags?

Comment: @tewathia: Yes. If you want to preserve the attributes, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8584098/218196).

Comment: Yeah, I have modified your code slightly to include that as well. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another/7093472?noredirect=1#comment30640487_7093472)

Answer (score 85):

This is much nicer:

```
$('code').contents().unwrap().wrap('<pre/>');
```

Though admittedly [Felix Kling's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another/7093472#7093472) is approximately [twice as fast](http://jsperf.com/substituting-one-tag-for-another-with-jquery):

Comment: worked like a charm, to my lay eyes this seems to be the most efficient solution. :)

Comment: aha. yea, you guys were right. it didn't work for me either. thanks for catching that!

Comment: FWIW, `$('code').children()` will return an empty jQuery object for the example above, because the `code` elements have no child element nodes. Though it works *if* there are child elements.

Comment: Fixed - true, when the contents consist of a single text node, `children()` won't work. Using `contents()` instead works perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/7Yne9/

Comment: as should be clear by now. i'm a bit lost in all this but you kind fellows seem to think this is the best solution and now that it's working i'll pass along what appreciate i can: my vote. thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Here is a jsperf version which does not break the page: http://jsperf.com/substituting-one-tag-for-another-with-jquery/2 and you see the speed difference is not that huge anymore. Your solution is slower because you perform two DOM manipulations per element: `unwrap` removes the parent and adds the children to the tree, `wrap` detaches them again and adds a new parent.

Comment: *Update:* Here is again a better jsperf: http://jsperf.com/substituting-one-tag-for-another-with-jquery/4 I think you have to reset the DOM every time you run the a test (otherwise there is nothing to do for the other iterations).

Comment: @Felix: thanks for the corrections - the performance hit is quite serious there. Too bad - I really liked the wrap-unwrap syntax. Although this is hardly a function which will be run in a loop or on huge pages of `<code>` tags, so performance may not be a big issue

Comment: @Jens: Exactly. Making benchmarks is good. But if there is no performance problem, then there is nothing to worry :)

Answer (score 29):

It's correct that you'll always obtain the first `code`'s contents, because `$('code').html()` will always refer to the first element, wherever you use it.

Instead, you could use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all elements and change each one individually:

```
$('code').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith( "<pre>" + $(this).html() + "</pre>" );
    // this function is executed for all 'code' elements, and
    // 'this' refers to one element from the set of all 'code'
    // elements each time it is called.
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$('code').each(function(){

    $(this).replaceWith( "<pre>" + $(this).html() + "</pre>" );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mTGhV/

Comment: wow. you guys came up with the exact same solution within 2 seconds of each other. there are tiny formatting differences. I'm not sure which one to upvote - I really don't like the space between function and () in thomas' answer and the 2 lines of empty space in kokos answer are pretty pointlness + there should be a space between the () and the {

Answer (score 14):

How about this?

```
$('code').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith( "<pre>" + $(this).html() + "</pre>" );
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Building up on Felix's answer.

```
$('code').replaceWith(function() {
    var replacement = $('<pre>').html($(this).html());
    for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
        replacement.attr(this.attributes[i].name, this.attributes[i].value);
    }
    return replacement;
});
```

This will reproduce the attributes of the `code` tags in the replacement `pre` tags.

Edit: This will replace even those `code` tags that are inside the `innerHTML` of other `code` tags.

```
function replace(thisWith, that) {
    $(thisWith).replaceWith(function() {
        var replacement = $('<' + that + '>').html($(this).html());
        for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
            replacement.attr(this.attributes[i].name, this.attributes[i].value);
        }
        return replacement;
    });
    if ($(thisWith).length>0) {
        replace(thisWith, that);
    }
}

replace('code','pre');
```

Comment: best answer so far. The other ones are pretty much all the same which is really odd that people upvote them. Congratz for being the only one that thought about the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

As of jQuery 1.4.2:

```
$('code').replaceWith(function(i,html) {
  return $('<pre />').html(html);
});​
```

You can then select the new elements:

```
$('pre').css('color','red');
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/#comment-45493689

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2swf/16/

Answer (score 2):

If you were using vanilla JavaScript you would:

- Create the new element
- Move the children of old element into the new element
- Insert the new element before the old one
- Remove the old element

Here is jQuery equivalent of this process:

```
$("code").each(function () {
    $("<pre></pre>").append(this.childNodes).insertBefore(this);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Here is the jsperf URL:
http://jsperf.com/substituting-one-tag-for-another-with-jquery/7

PS: All solutions that use `.html()` or `.innerHTML` are ***destructive***.

Answer (score 2):

All answers given here assume (as the question example indicates) that there are no attributes in the tag. If the accepted answer is ran on this:

```
<code class='cls'>A</code>
```

if will be replaced with

```
<pre>A</pre>
```

What if you want to keep the attributes as well - which is what replacing a tag would mean... ? This is the solution:

```
$("code").each( function(){
    var content = $( "<pre>" );

    $.each( this.attributes, function(){ 
         content.attr( this.name, this.value );
    } );

    $( this ).replaceWith( content );
} );
```

Comment: I know this is a couple of years old but I just thought I'd mention... you forgot to keep the html from the previous element. In your code snippet you're just creating a new element with the attributes without copying any of the children over as well.

Comment: that would be done by adding `content.html( this.html )`

Answer (score 2):

Another short & easy way:

```
$('code').wrapInner('<pre />').contents();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('code').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith( "<pre>" + $(this).html()  + "</pre>" );
    });
```

Best and clean way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's html function. Below is a sample the replaces a code tag with a pre tag while retaining all of the attributes of the code.

```
    $('code').each(function() {
        var temp=$(this).html();
        temp=temp.replace("code","pre");
        $(this).html(temp);
    });
```

This could work with any set of html element tags that needed to be swapped while retaining all the attributes of the previous tag.

Answer (score 0):

Made `jquery` plugin, maintaining attributes also.

```
$.fn.renameTag = function(replaceWithTag){
  this.each(function(){
        var outerHtml = this.outerHTML;
        var tagName = $(this).prop("tagName");
        var regexStart = new RegExp("^<"+tagName,"i");
        var regexEnd = new RegExp("</"+tagName+">$","i")
        outerHtml = outerHtml.replace(regexStart,"<"+replaceWithTag)
        outerHtml = outerHtml.replace(regexEnd,"</"+replaceWithTag+">");
        $(this).replaceWith(outerHtml);
    });
    return this;
}
```

Usage:

```
$('code').renameTag('pre')
```