# replace all <td>content</td> with <li>content</li> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to remove all tags: `table`, `tbody`, `tr` from my HTML code ? At the end I would like replece all

```
<td>
    <input id="selectOne" type="radio" value="1" name="selectOneRadio">   
</td>
```

with

```
<li>
    <input id="selectOne" type="radio" value="1" name="selectOneRadio"> 
</li>
```

I need a jQuery function. Please help me :)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="selectOne" type="radio" value="1" name="selectOneRadio">
                <label for="selectOne">
            </td>  
       </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

*from comment...*

The `label` element should stay. I tried with:

```
$('table td').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>')
    })
});
```

and then

```
jQuery.fn.unwrap = function (el) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this.childNodes).appendTo(this.parentNode);
    });
};
$('tr, table, tbody').unwrap().remove();
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here, we help you to overcome your coding problems... but first, you need to help yourself and attempt something. When you get stuck, THEN ask for help. Not many people in this world like to work for free, but many are happy to help problem solve.

Comment: SO is not 'programmer for free' service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to remove the `label` elements too? Or was that just an accidental omission?

Comment: @PatrykMeyer: Adding that much code to a comment is almost useless. I updated your question with that information.

Comment: <label> tag is not closed, that might cause some issues

Comment: Why was this closed? (1) This is not localized IMO. How does one replace one html tag with another tag using jquery is perfectly acceptable. (2) In fact the answer is somewhat in the question already. Test it out http://jsbin.com/usotus/3/edit#html,javascript,live

Comment: @sivy see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another

Answer (score 2):

Create a list with `document.createElement`. Then loop through the table's `rows[]` array and, for each one, take the `cells[]` array and do what you need to in order to get it in a list item (maybe `document.createElement` to create the list item, then copy the `innerHTML` of the cell into it).

Once that's done, use `insertBefore` to put the list where the table was, and finally use `removeChild` to get rid of the table.

---

Implementation of the above:

```
function replaceTableWithList(tableid) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableid),
        rows = table.rows, cells, list = document.createElement('ul'),
        len = rows.length, i, item;
    for( i=0; i<len, i++) {
        item = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
        cells = rows[i].cells;
        while(cells[0].firstChild) item.appendChild(cells[0].firstChild);
        // this only gets the contents of the first cell in a row
        // to get the whole row will need another loop
    }
    table.parentNode.replaceChild(list,table);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the OP requested a jQuery solution.

Comment: Using jQuery for this is like taking a sledgehammer to a nail to hang up a photo.

Comment: +1 for a native solution. You could also use `replaceChild` instead of `insertBefore/removeChild`

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks for reminding me of that function.

Comment: @Esailija I have corrected myself in the implementation I edited in. Now the nodes themselves are moved over.

Comment: @Kolink actually, Cyber's answer is a pretty elegant and concise way to do this with jQuery. More like pulling out your toolbox and using your 3/4" phillips. I wouldn't recommend using jQuery solely for this purpose, but if you're using it already, there's no reason not to do something like Cyber's answer. And from the looks of the question, he is.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your for loop, replace comma with semicolon . `for( i=0; i<len; i++) {`

Comment: Also for what it is worth this function is dependant on  `getElementById(tableid)` and having an ID attribute set. OP did not have an ID, so you might want to modify to show an alternate way maybe loop through tables or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I would use unwrap/wrap functionality:

`$('table').contents().unwrap();
$('tr').contents().unwrap();
$('td').contents().unwrap().wrap('<li/>');`

Comment: I hope you realise this annahiliates every single table on the page, when the OP may just want to affect one table?

Comment: But he did not mention anywhere it's about one specific table. :)

Comment: I'm getting error : SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

...().unwrap(); $('tr').contents().unwrap(); $('td').contents().unwrap().wrap('<li

Comment: @Cyber How to remove **all tags**: table, tbody, tr

Comment: I don't see where the error could come from. :( Could you post the whole code?

Comment: If you would like to remove all table tags just remove the ending of the code above that wraps table cells content with with <li> tags.

So it would be something like this:

$('table').contents().unwrap();

$('tr').contents().unwrap();

$('td').contents().unwrap();

Comment: This does not work as expected in this example it adds 5 `<li>` tags with some of them being empty and it also leaves behind the `<tbody>` tag. http://jsbin.com/onovis/1/

Comment: It only replaces `<td>` tag with `<li>` tag as for the `<tbody>` tag it could be replaced or unwrapped the same way as other tags just one more line to be added: `$('tbody').contents().unwrap();` Well, I just wanted to help, unwrap seemed to me best jquery option but surely there are other more advanced ways too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap your table in some kind of container:

```
<div id="content">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>​​​​
```

Then using jQuery and do something like this:

```
// Hide the table
$('#content table').hide();

// Append a ul to the content div
$('<ul />').appendTo('#content');

// For each td, wrap children in an li and append to the ul​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
$('#content table td').each(function (index, element) {
    $(element).children().appendTo('#content ul').wrap('<li />');
});
```