# jquery replace all <ol> with <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given the following dom structure I would like to transform an ordered list to an unordered list.

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <ol>
    <li><div>foo</div></li>
    <ol>
      <li><div>bar</div></li>
    </ol>
    <li><div>batz</div></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: No need for a regex based on your example.

Comment: Regex is not a good solution when you are trying to parse HTML or XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: well i thought maybe getting the string and replacing it with regex would be faster than doing it with jquery.

Comment: @supernova There is no performance concern unless there is a performance concern ..

Comment: There are some excellent answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12510109/981208

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i had to work from the inside to the outside, only replaceWith wasn't working because it replaced only the outer tags and didn't replace the inner ones, so i solved it this way:

```
$($('.wrapper').find('ol').get().reverse()).each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith($('<ul>'+$(this).html()+'</ul>'))
})
```

if someone has a better solution i would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [jQuery replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).