# Replace <A> tag with <DIV> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I have the following code:

```
<div class="normal">
    <div>
        <div>~Content 1~</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="normal replace">
    <a href="#">
        <div>~Content 2~</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I want to replace the `<a>` tag inside `<div class="normal replace">` with normal `<div>` tag while keeping it's content.

```
<div class="normal replace">
    <div="result">
        <div>~Content 2~</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There must be so many duplicates of this question...

Comment: Please write <div="result"> in the right format. I think you forgot to mention id or class.

Comment: @vinothini This is clearly an example, does that really matter! ;-)

Comment: @Zenith unfortunately, there are only solutions for changing div's content, not replacing the div while keeping it's content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('.normal > a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<div/>', {
        html: this.innerHTML
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VMxAL/

Comment: What's exactly are you returning?
I don't understand the structure of what you're returning.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
// Select the 'a' tag to be replaced and call the replaceWith method
$('.normal a').replaceWith(function(){
    // Execute a callback to generate contents of the replacement
    // The $('<div>') part creates a div
    return $('<div>', {
        html: this.innerHTML // This takes the html of the 'a' tag and copies it to the new div
    });
});
```

The jQuery `replaceWith` method takes the the item and replaces it with what is returned by the callback function.

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) for more information

Comment: Should the return be `return $('<div>` or `return $('<div/>'` ?

Answer (score 2):

here you go orignally take from here [Using jQuery to replace one tag with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another)

```
$('div.normal a').contents().unwrap().wrap('<div id='result'/>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
$('div.normal.replace a').find('div').unwrap().wrap("<div id='result'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following
$('div.normal.replace a').replaceWith( "" + $('div.normal.replace a').html() + "" );

Answer (score 0):

Please click on the jsfiddle example i tried for you below.

`Click here for JS Fiddle example`

Hope that helps.