# How to replace html element with ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How do I replace the html element from ajax response? What I know to is to remove the element, how do I replace that removed tag with ajax response?
For example:

I have code like this:

```
<ul id="products">
...............
</ul>
```

When I click on a button the ajax call is made to codeginter controller where I recieve the new data pulled from the database and rendered in another view which starts from ul and ends at closing ul.

In ajax success function I do this:

```
$('#products').remove();
//What to do now here to replace the removed portion with response of ajax?
```

Comment: You could use `.append` or `.html` based on what you want. Remember, `.remove` removes the element altogether, probably you need `.empty` Show us what was returned from `AJAX`, is it all `<li>`? If so you could just use `.html` which also empties the content and puts the new content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to replace one tag with another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another)

Comment: Do you want to replace the whole UL, or just fill in the contents?

Comment: Where is the rest of your ajax code?  Depending on the format of your response.. if your response is in html format then all you need to do is append the response to `#products`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use replaceWith (see: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Like: `$('#products').replaceWith(response);`

Comment: It is working but the replaced content is ruptured/not well-formed. Let me tell that the new view has slightly changed HTML. Older one shows results in grid format and newer in list format. For replaceWith function the structure of new and old HTML has to be exactly same?

Comment: Try `$('#products').replaceWith($(response));` maybe. If the styling appears to be different, maybe check your CSS selectors. They need to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: The replaceWith function mentioned by pascalvgemert is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527642/2887034

Create a wrapper around it:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="products">
    ...............
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now you can do the following:

```
$('#wrapper').html(responseData);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are replacing your products, if you are getting formatted HTML from your controller then simply do this

```
success : function(response) {
$('#products').html(response);
}
```

No need to remove < ul > tag. You can simply replace old < li >s with new < li >s

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```
$('#products').before("yourhtmlreceivedfromajax").remove();
```

Or just replace the content of the div with [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) `$('#products').html("yourhtmlreceivedfromajax");`

Answer (score 2):

If your main div is inside another container with another id, you could do so:

Based on this structure:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <ul id="products">
         ...............
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript code using jquery for ajax**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "action.php",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(response) {
  $('#products').remove(); // you can keep this line if you think is necessary
  $('mainContainer').html(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is wrap your ul in a container

```
<div id="container">
<ul id="products">
...............
</ul>
</div>
```

in ajax response

```
success:function(data){
$("#container").html(data)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) takes the element completely out of the DOM. If you simply want to replace stuff inside the `products` element, you use [.ReplaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

If you are returning all `<li>` as HTML, you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
$( "ul#products" ).replaceWith( response );
```

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/