# Updating an HTML fragment with ajax response Django using CBV(ListView)

Tags: python, ajax, django

So I have a homepage that consists of a base listview which includes all of the objects from my db(as shown in the cbv .all() query). What I wanted to do is include a search filter, hence I thought it would be a good idea to isolate it into a separate "list.html" fragment in order to make it reusable later on. Currently, I have an ajax call that sends information to the cbv and the return is a render to list.html fragment. However, when I visit the homepage, the page doesn't get rendered to begin with.

Help or advice would be very much appreciated, thank you again.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', exp_view.DrugListView.as_view() , name = 'drug_list')]
```

here is my CBV template:

**views.py**

```
class DrugListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'drugs'
model = Drug
template_name = 'expirations/drug_list.html'

def get(self, request):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        text_to_search = self.request.GET.get('searchText')
        print(text_to_search)
        return render(request, "expirations/list.html", {'drug':Drug.objects.filter(name__contains = text_to_search).order_by('name')})
    else:
        return render(request, "expirations/list.html", {'drug':Drug.objects.all().order_by('name')})
```

here is
**drug_list.html**

```
{% extends 'expirations/index.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% include 'expirations/list.html' %}

{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input = $("#searchText")
    input.keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'drug_list' %}",
      data: {'searchText' : input.val()},
      success: function(data){
        $("#list_view").load("expirations/list.html")
        }
    })
    });
})
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

here is **list.html**:

```
{% for drug in drugs %}
    <div class = '.col-sm-12'>
        <ul class = 'list-group'>
            <li class = "list-group-item" >
              <span class = "badge">First Expiration: {{ drug.early_exp|date:"l M d Y" }}</span>
              <a href="{% url 'drug_detail' pk=drug.pk %}">{{ drug.name }}</a>
              {% regroup drug.expiration_dates.all by facility as facility_list %}
              {% for x in facility_list %}
              <span class="label label-info">{{ x.grouper }}</span>
              {% endfor %}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what you need to do in your `success` callback.

That function has no access to Django templates. But it doesn't need to, because Django has already sent the fragment in the response, which is available in the `data` parameter. You just need to insert that into the existing page.

For that you'll need a container; so you should modify your drug_list.html so that there is a div around the include:

```
{% block content %}

<div id="list_contents">
  {% include 'expirations/list.html' %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and now your success function can be:

```
  success: function(data) {
    $("#list_contents").html(data)
 }
```

Comment: This definitely helped alot. Is there a guide to learn what the scope of the success function for ajax calls?

Comment: @hpca01 it has the response django sent, That's all

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it will work this way. For Ajax calls and CBV look at [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example).

Then you would need to return the new, filtered data (in html format) to the ajax call and [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527586/how-to-replace-html-element-with-ajax-response/19527642#19527642) the html in the sucess function via JS.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Roseman definitely helped solve the puzzle, here is the updated code:

**views.py**: updated if/else statement to include a default list view of the general template. also added the context name 'drugs' instead of 'drug'

```
class DrugListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'drugs'
    model = Drug
    template_name = 'expirations/drug_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            text_to_search = self.request.GET.get('searchText')
            print(text_to_search)
            return render(request, "expirations/list.html", {'drugs':Drug.objects.filter(name__contains = text_to_search).order_by('name')})
        else:
            return render(request, "expirations/drug_list.html", {'drugs':Drug.objects.all().order_by('name')})
```

**drug_list.html**: changed success callback function load html as suggested by daniel.

```
{% extends 'expirations/index.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div id = 'list_view'>
  {% include 'expirations/list.html' %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input = $("#searchText")
    input.keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'drug_list' %}",
      data: {'searchText' : input.val()},
      success: function(data){
        $("#list_view").html(data)
        }
    })
    });
})
</script>
{% endblock %}
```