# How to convert html elements and properties to something else with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Nothing major, but I need to know if there is a way for me to change html elements with containing properties to something else with jquery.

What I actually want to do is to change the following piece of markup after a page load:

```
<div class="stretchMe" data-stretch="@Url.Content("Images/img1.jpg")"></div>
```

to

```
<img class="stretchMe" src="@Url.Content("Images/img1.jpg")" />
```

How to do something like this?

Comment: Can be easily modified to rename the attribute as well. Or alternatively: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another.

Comment: @user3827886 Take a look bala answer please he is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**

### html

`<div class="stretchMe" data-stretch="@Url.Content(Images/img1.jpg)"></div>`

### JS

```
$("div.stretchMe").each(function () {

    var class1 = $(this).attr("class");

    var src = $(this).data("stretch");

    $(this).replaceWith("<img class=" + class1 + " src='" + src + "' />");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p2t4y/)

### OP

```
<img class="stretchMe" src="@Url.Content(Images/img1.jpg)">
```