# Rearrange DOM elements according to given standard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I will try do describe the issue:

I'm using contenteditable to edit text in DIV. The standard for elements I need to have in that DIV is:

paragraph:

```
<p style="someStyles"><span style="someStyles">TEXT GOES HERE</span></p>
```

empty line:

```
<p style="someStyles"><span style="someStyles"><br></span></p>
```

Due to some user text manipulations like copy/paste standard is messed in that DIV like here (ex. of case):

```
<span style="someStyles">
    <p style="someStyles">SOME TEXT HERE</p>
    <p style="someStyles">SOME TEXT HERE</p>
</span>
```

Im looking for a solution that will take messed text elements and rearrange it to given standard I wrote about above, any suggestions ?

After rearranging elements it should look like this:

```
<p style="someStyles">
    <span style="someStyles">SOME TEXT HERE</span>
    <span style="someStyles">SOME TEXT HERE</span>
</p>
```

P.S - I want to make that rearrange function on keyup event while typing and only for whole p element that caret is on.

Comment: You forgot to paste the code you tried. Showing a sample where one can reproduce the issue might help. How you're adding your SPAN elements and classes?

Comment: Your standard can be messed up in infinitely many ways by the user. You gave one example (which is solvable), but if I understand correctly, you are asking for an algorithm that can convert any kind off mess to your standard (which isn't solvable).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan text is the same as paragraph described above with empty lines between. I will try to provide some more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, I can't see a general solution to this, but your specific example could be solved like this. And you can easily make several other conversions based on this one.

The `replace` function is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20493562/2381321).

```
// this converts an element to another tag
function replace(thisWith, that) {
    $(thisWith).replaceWith(function() {
        var i, replacement = $('<' + that + '>').html($(this).html());
        for (i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++) {
            replacement.attr(this.attributes[i].name, this.attributes[i].value);
        }
        return replacement;
    });
}

function convert() {
    // get SPANs that has Ps inside
    var $spans = $("#content span").has("p");
    $spans.each(function () {
        // change children Ps into SPANs
        replace($(this).children("p"), "span");
        // change parent SPAN into P
        replace(this, "p");        
    });
}
```

Here is a test [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/b1gdxcx1/2/).

Comment: It works as intented for that case, but that was the question. thx!