# Jquery remove <i> and </i> tag from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string:

```
var x = "hi<i>zz</i>2<i>bbb</i>";
```

And want this output:

```
hizz2bbb
```

My code not working fine:

```
value.replace(/\<\i\>/g, '');
```

Or

```
value.replace(/\<i>/g, '');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jQuery to replace one tag with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me.

```js
var x = "hi<i>zz</i>2<i>bbb</i>";
x = x.replace(/<\/?i>/g, ""); // hizz2bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for it:

```
console.log($("<i>hi<i>zz</i>2<i>bbb</i></i>").text())
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove any HTML tags.

```
x.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');
```